# i want to print ul width in tag of ul with the help of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to print ul width in tag of ul with the help of jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var fixmeTop = $('ul').offset().top;
  alert($("ul").width());
});
```

```css
ul li{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you want to add the value returned from the `width()` call to a new `li` tag within the `ul`. If so you can use the `append()` method to do this:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var fixmeTop = $('ul').offset().top;
  $("ul").append('<li>' + fixmeTop + '</li>');
});
```

```css
ul li{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to print width in `<ul>` tag with the help of jquery.

```
<ul style="width:250px">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```